# Python pandas to compare 2 Microsoft Excel and output the changes

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use Python pandas to determine the changes need to make on a certain rows.

data1

```
name   contract   id    unit  qty  location
siteA  00012345  A001   pcs    1    M.K.141.1
siteA  00012345  A002   pcs    2    M.K.141.1
siteA  00012345  A003   pcs    3    M.K.141.1
siteA  00012345  A004   pcs    12   M.K.141.1
siteA  00012345  A005   pcs    26   M.K.141.1
siteA  00012345  A006   pcs    2    M.K.141.1
siteB  00012345  A001   pcs    2    M.K.285.1
siteB  00012345  A003   pcs    3    M.K.285.1
siteB  00012345  A004   pcs    5    M.K.285.1
siteB  00012345  A005   pcs    10   M.K.285.1
siteB  00012345  A006   pcs    11   M.K.285.1
```

data2

```
name   id   unit   qty
siteA  A001  pcs    1
siteA  A002  pcs    4 
siteA  A003  pcs    6 
siteA  A004  pcs    12
siteA  A005  pcs    28
siteB  A001   pcs   2 
siteB  A003   pcs   6 
siteB  A004   pcs   5 
siteB  A005   pcs   33
siteB  A006   pcs   11
```

What I am trying to figure out is to compare data2 with data1, and check the difference of the qty between both siteA and siteB respectively, and modify the qty in data1

need some head start as looking into pandas documentation takes me too long to able to understand what to do..

thanks!

code snippet I current have:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel(r'D:\data1.xlsx', 'Sheet1')
df2 = pd.read_excel(r'D:\data2.xlsx', 'Sheet1')

for index, row in df1.iterrow():
    pass
```

too bad i am too new to pandas and trying to learn how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I'd use merge to join those to datasets together then look for differences.

```
data1.merge(data2, on=['name','id','unit']).query('qty_x != qty_y')
```

Output:

```
    name  contract    id unit  qty_x   location  qty_y
1  siteA     12345  A002  pcs      2  M.K.141.1      4
2  siteA     12345  A003  pcs      3  M.K.141.1      6
4  siteA     12345  A005  pcs     26  M.K.141.1     28
6  siteB     12345  A003  pcs      3  M.K.285.1      6
8  siteB     12345  A005  pcs     10  M.K.285.1     33
```

Where _x and _y are default suffixes giving to commonly named columns in each dataframe. You can't redefine these suffixes using the `suffixes` parameter in merge.

Comment: this works.. Thanks.. But I would like to see if there is any other method to use..

Comment: @ReverseEngineer What sort of method are you thinking?

Comment: @ReverseEngineer Okay.  Well, I think this is the most efficient way to get the difference between data1 and data2.